# Create an array then fill it up one place at the time with a key command?

Tags: excel, vba

Beginner here! :)

I want to take the value from a cell and put in an array using a key command.

I work in a warehouse and there a big screen on the wall that shows the number of orders left to deliver. It's an excel file I made. I want to take that number and put it in an array every minute. Then, once it reach 60 minutes I want to compare the value now with the value an hour ago and display it in a cell. Effectively showing how many orders that were delivered during the last 60 minutes.

I'm trying to create one sub routine that creates the array then another sub routine that fills the array up. Start the first subroutine manually, then start the second sub routine with a key command, pressed by a AutoHotKey script every 60 second. I'm a bit of a beginner at VBA, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

First sub:

```
sub createarray() 'this sub is started once to create the array and variables

dim CellStatus(1 to 121)
dim c as long = 1
dim WorkSpeed as long
end sub
```

The second sub:

```
sub AddToArray()      'this sub is started once every 60 seconds via a key command
CellStatus(c)=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("searchresult").cells(a1).Value 'puts the cellvalue in the array

if c>60
WorkSpeed = Cellstatus(c-60)-Cellstatus(c)  'compare the value 60 minutes ago

else if c<61
Workspeed = Cellstatus(c+60)-Cellstatus(c)  'compare the value 60 minutes ago
end if

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("showresult").cells(d6).value=Workspeed 'puts whats inside the variable WorkSpeed in cell d6 in the sheet "showresults"
c = c + 1

if c=121
CellStatus(1)=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("searchresult").cells(a1).Value 'copies the value of Cell A1 in both place 121 and 1 in the array.
c=2
else
c=c+1
end if



end sub
```

Am I doing it right? See any errors in the code?
/Jens

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many errors in your code. Too many to address here.The extent of errors suggests you should work your way through a tutorial on VBA. In the meantime, put 'Option explicit' at the start of your code to more clearly show up errors. Use MS help for VBA/excel by placing the cursor on a keyword and pressing 'F1' to bring up help pages.